# Get records which are last updated in n minutes in jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

I am working on a jpa query which requires to fetch all the records whose last updated time is more than 15 minutes
My query goes like

```
Select * from user u where u.last_modified >= NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes'
```

I will be passing the minutes dynamically ie in my jpa

```
@Query("Select * from user u where u.last_modified >= NOW() - INTERVAL ':timeInMinutes minutes'")
getRecord(String timeInMinutes);
```

This does not work. I want to pass the minute dynamically. Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this trick:

```
@Query("""
        SELECT * from user u WHERE 
        u.last_modified >= (NOW() - (INTERVAL '1' minutes) * :timeInMinutes)
        """, nativeQuery = true)
SomeType getRecord(Long timeInMinutes);
```

The idea here is to multiply `timeInMinutes` by `1`, which will give you always `timeInMinutes`.

Note: the type of timeInMinutes should be a number, and also you have to use `nativeQuery = true` because your query is not a JPA syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much  had to change from (INTERVAL '1' minutes)  to (INTERVAL '1' minute) for the above query to work

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer failed with syntax error on my end but I was able to rewrite it and this worked, query would return all user records modified X minutes ago.

```
    @Query(value = """
    SELECT * from user u WHERE 
    u.last_modified <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :timeInMinutes minute)
    """, nativeQuery = true)
    SomeType getRecord(Long timeInMinutes);
```